# What formal rules are there around place names in Words with Friends?

Tags: words-with-friends

So I was playing Words with Friends for iOS, and I thought I was cleverly using up my "Q" without a "U" by playing "[Qatar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qatar)". However my word was rejected.

Are there any place names, such as landmarks, cities, countries etc that are allowed in Words with Friends?

Comment: I think it would be better to restrict your question to Words With Friends; there's no guarantee each game has similar rules, and a broad question about Scrabble and its clones sounds like a question about [Board and Card Games](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All names starting with capital letter are forbidden. Places, cities, countries, rivers, but also first and last names,

Comment: To clarify though, there are some words that are proper nouns that are also 'regular' words (i.e. sally, japan, polish, etc)

Comment: What does the word 'japan' mean?  (as opposed to 'Japan', the country)  I understand your other examples, but I've never come across 'japan' before.

Comment: @chris browne - I believe it something to do with a coating on metal, like a lacquer layer on tools, etc.

Comment: @Chris, Kurley's right: it can refer to [either a hard, durable, black varnish or the process of applying it](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/japan). I didn't know it was an acceptable word either.

Comment: I'm never playing scrabble with @Gwen.

Comment: I am pretty sure I learned that from a movie - the girl (boy?) was playing Scrabble while coaching a friend at boxing through a headset, and won the game when the oppenent challenged japan as a word and failed.

Answer (score 0):

Words with friends will let you play Amin as in Idi Amin. It is only used as a name and the WWF definition actually refers to the man himself with his dates in power, etc.